# Sharing Pixel Buffer object and synchronization of two OpenGL context

Tags: multithreading, opengl, glsl, glfw

I am creating a thread in my program.
Than i am creating a second OpenGL context for this thread and share it with the main thread's context.

When i try to read The data in the thread from PBO using glMapBuffer the pointer returns nullptr. Also how can i synchronize the two threads.

This is the first time i am working with two different threads and had lot of trouble even creating two different threads.

Please look at my code and advise me how i can make it work.

This is the code for the thread.

The shaders are basic shaders.

```
void wnd2func(void)
{
    GLFWwindow *wnd2 = glfwCreateWindow(400, 300, "window 2", 0, wnd);
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        wnd2created = true;
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    if (wnd2 == nullptr)
        return;

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd2);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    glGenBuffers(2, pbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, SCR_WIDTH *SCR_HEIGHT * 3, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, SCR_WIDTH *SCR_HEIGHT * 3, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);   

    while (true)
    {
        writeIndex = (writeIndex + 1) % 2;
        readIndex = (writeIndex + 1) % 2;
        // bind PBO to read pixels. This buffer is being copied from GPU to CPU memory

        glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[0]);
        // copy from framebuffer to PBO asynchronously. it will be ready in the NEXT frame
        glReadPixels(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
        // now read other PBO which should be already in CPU memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[0]);
        // map buffer so we can access it
        void* downsampleData = (unsigned char *)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
    //  std::cout << "Yes Downsample";
        if (downsampleData)
        {
            std::cout << "Able to read the data";
        }
        downsampleData = nullptr;
    }
}
```

This is the code for main in which i am creating a simple cube object

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include"Shader.h"
#include <stb_image.h>
#include "Camera.h"
#include <map>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
int readIndex = 0;
int writeIndex = 1;
GLuint pbo[2];

GLFWwindow *wnd = nullptr;
bool wnd2created = false;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 400;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 300;
// camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
//  GLFWwindow* sharedWindow = NULL;
    wnd = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Test", 0, nullptr );
    std::thread wnd2thread(wnd2func);
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cv.wait(lck, []() -> bool { return wnd2created; });
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd);

    if (wnd == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(wnd, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float cubeVertices[] = {
        // positions          // texture Coords
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    // cube VAO
        unsigned int cubeVAO, cubeVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeVertices), &cubeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    Shader shader("C:\\Shaders\\OpenGL_GUI\\Video\\Vertex.txt", "C:\\Shaders\\OpenGL_GUI\\Video\\Fragment.txt");    
    shader.use();
    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(wnd))
    {
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth testing (is disabled for rendering screen-space quad)
        // make sure we clear the framebuffer's content
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        shader.use();
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        shader.setMat4("view", view);
        shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        // cubes
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glfwSwapBuffers(wnd);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Since you never unmap the buffer, every attempt after the first one will error out. Also, initializing glew twice in parallel might have some very odd consequences. But furthermore: what are you even trying to achieve with this construct?

Comment: @derhass i want to give SDI out from the application using bluefish card , their SDk needs the pointer from glMapBuffer.

Comment: But they have blocking functions to sync with their card and this function also blocks the Main thread.

Comment: So we need to do this in another thread.

Comment: @derhass do i need to sync both the threads ?

Comment: Your readpixel approach from the second thread simply won't work. It reads the contents of your seconde window (which are undefined).

Comment: @derhass I am sharing the context of the first window.

Comment: @derhass if you could please help me with how i can do this.

Comment: you don't need a second GL context for that, you can (and have to) rend into the PBO from your main thread and context, you can map that and use another thread to access the buffer contents while mapped

Comment: @derhass would i need any synchronization between both the threads in this case.

Comment: of course you need proper ways of synchronization

Comment: sorry, but I think that is way outside the scope of Stackoverflow.